# Rundeck jobs fail when powershell script hits any error. NonZeroResultCode

Tags: powershell, exit-code, rundeck, winrm

Rundeck 4.8.0 community version on Redhat 9 Linux with Windows node.
My Rundeck jobs call powershell (.ps1) scripts on the windows node.
If there are any errors encountered in the script, the Rundeck job dies.
The rundeck output gives the NonZeroResultCode message

NonZeroResultCode: [WinRMPython] Result code: 1

There's more code that needs to be run after where the error occurred, but Rundeck just dies and doesn't continue the rest of the .ps1.

I previously used Rundeck version 3.something, I thing it was 3.9.

If there was an error in the script, such as a get or a set failed, the Rundeck console would just display the text of the error in red, and continue.

Now I know I can change my code and add try/catch statements, -erroraction SilentlyContinue and so on. However it makes no sense to me that Rundeck takes it upon itself to kill my script because a get or a set failed.

I want to be the one to decide if I want to exit the script or not, I don't want Rundeck to make that decision.

Can this behavior be changed?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's the default Rundeck behavior.

You can "attach" an error handler on that script-step (on any step actually), e.g: the error handler could be the script code when your step fails.

The error handler feature is designed for that kind of scenario, take a look at [this](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/manual/job-workflows.html#error-handlers).

Comment: Thanks. I took a look and am having trouble figuring it out. My step isn't failing, a command in the powershell script is failing. I cannot see how to create an error handler for that. Here is an example of an error. Trying to get a file, but the file doesnt exist ... ERROR ] Execution finished with the following error (winrm-exec.py:323)[root] [ERROR ] get-content : Cannot find path 'E:\FileUploads\72cc8809-7d2b-41c2-85f6-83e48546b2ab' because it does not exist. Failed: NonZeroResultCode: [WinRMPython] Result code: 1